# Properly exchange items between multiples RecyclerViews

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

Being objective, my goal is simple (or not), drag a recycler's item to other one in my activity.

The scenario is the following.

I have a list of items, let's call them sections, and inside a section another list of items, of another type, the elements.

I want exchange the elements between the sections. The list of sections isn't fixed, can be changed adding and removing a section, but hasn't any movement behavior. The elements also can be added and removed from a section, but have this reorder approach.

I've found some strategies with fixed "section". [Here](https://sunny89blog.wordpress.com/2017/07/16/transfer-items-from-one-recyclerview-to-another-and-vice-versa/) is an example. This one uses drag and drop to make the exchange. But it's too simple. For example, don't consider the need to scroll recycle when the dragging reaches bottom or top of visible elements. That's because it has only two lists. Does Drag and Drop have this behavior, forcing the scroll?

Is there any way to do this using the `ItemTouchHelper`? If so, how would it be? `ItemTouchHelper` seems better, 'cause considers the scroll problem and has a more intuitive reorder animation.

If you think of a better approach than using recyclers, feel free to indicate such strategy to me.

Answer (score 0):

You use drag and drop for the dragging and dropping, the scrolling and such you'd have to make yourself using the appropriate events in the OnDragListener.